# No valid crumb was included in the request even when crum is provided

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to call jenkins job from python script. I could get the request working in postman. But from the script it is giving me error 403. Below is my code snippet on what I have tried. Let me know if I am missing something.

I have seen posts on the crumb not working. In my request I am getting the crumb and passing in the post api call. But still it does not seem to work.

```
jenkinsUrl = "url/buildWithParameters?token=1122"
getcrumb=requests.get('https://jenkins.com/crumbIssuer/api/xml?xpath=concat(//crumbRequestField,":",//crumb)')
crumb = json.dumps(getcrumb.content)
headers_data = {'Jenkins-Crumb':crumb, 'Content-
Type':'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}

response = requests.post(jenkinsUrl,auth=('xxxx','xxxx'),
headers=headers_data, data=job_payload)
print("response", response.text)
```

The data I get from the get call for crumb is something like this. 
    'Jenkins-Crumb': 'c5cc280ddab3fb07d7bf5ae1f254f44e'
I am stripping the crumb value from it and passing it to the header.

This is the header I see going in the requests when making the call.

```
 {'Content-Length': '130', 'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate', 
 'Accept': '*/*', 'User-Agent': 'python-requests/2.18.4', 'Connection': 
 'keep-alive', 'Jenkins-Crumb': 'b9fdfc403f9bc2eccc1f0410b0e55ca2', 
 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded', 'Authorization': 
 'Basic ZnNqZW5raW5zdXNlcjpDYXBpdGFsMg=='}
```

Comment: This has been resolved with passing the authentication details in the get call when getting the crumb. I see I was not passing in the auth when getting the data.

Comment: I believe you should consider posting it as an answer.